# MYSQL: update record random 2 fixed char

Tags: mysql

i would like to update all record on a field which i only want it to fill it with random either **Y** or **N**

currently using:

> update table1 set field1=( SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM Y FOR N)

which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 set field1 = case floor(1 + rand()*2) when 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set field1= if(RAND() > 0.5,"Y","N")
```